# Modify Script to Include DIV around AM/PM

Tags: javascript

How can I modify this script to encase the AM/PM text in a div?

I already tried modifying the areas where it outputs the ampm with a div, but it didnt put the element in a div, instead displaying the  and  tags as plaintext.

```
function myTime() {
var dst = 0;       // set to 1 for daylight savings time
                   // update this as you go on and off daylight saving time
var loc = ''; // set to your location
var mtz = -5;      // set to your local timezone (hours ahead of UTC, negative if behind)
var stdz = ''; // standard time indicator
var dayz = ''; // daylight saving time indicator (blank if you dont have daylight saving)
var showDate = 0; // 0 = don't show, 1 = international format, 2 = US format

// do not alter anything below this line
var newP = document.createElement("div"); var txt = '' + loc + ' '; var newT = document.createTextNode(txt); newP.appendChild(newT); var newP2 = document.createElement("div"); newP2.id = 'time'; var txt2 = setDsp(mtz,dst,stdz,dayz,showDate); var newT2 = document.createTextNode(txt2); newP2.appendChild(newT2); var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(); frag.appendChild(newP); frag.appendChild(newP2); var d2 = document.getElementById('datetime'); d2.parentNode.replaceChild(frag,d2);
setTimeout('updDsp('+mtz+',' +dst+',"' +stdz+'","' +dayz+'","'+showDate+'")', 5000);}
var pageLoaded = 0; window.onload = function() {pageLoaded = 1;}
function loaded(i,f) {if (document.getElementById && document.getElementById(i) != null) f(); else if (!pageLoaded) setTimeout('loaded(\''+i+'\','+f+')',100);
}
function updDsp(mtz,dst,stdz,dayz,showDate) {var obj = document.getElementById('time'); obj.firstChild.data = setDsp(mtz,dst,stdz,dayz,showDate); setTimeout('updDsp('+mtz+ ','+dst+ ',"'+stdz+ '","'+dayz+ '","'+showDate+'")', 5000);}
function setDsp(mtz,dst,stdz,dayz,showDate) {var dayname = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday']; var month = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']; var now = new Date; now.setUTCMinutes(now.getUTCMinutes() + (mtz + dst)*60); var dow = now.getUTCDay(); var minute = now.getUTCMinutes();
var hour = now.getUTCHours(); if (hour > 11) {ampm = 'PM'; hour -= 12;} else {ampm = 'AM'} if (hour == 0) {hour = 12;} if (minute < 10) {pad = ':0';} else {pad = ':';} var txt = hour + pad + minute + ' ' + '' + ampm + ''; if (dst) txt += dayz; else txt += stdz; txt += ' '
if (showDate == 1) txt += ' ' + now.getUTCDate() + ' '  + month[now.getUTCMonth()]  + ', ' + now.getUTCFullYear();
if (showDate == 2) txt += ' ' + month[now.getUTCMonth()] +' '  + now.getUTCDate() + ', ' + now.getUTCFullYear();
return (txt);
}
loaded('datetime',myTime);
```

Comment: eek, can you fix the code formatting?

Comment: Also - this is easy enough, but requires a lot of code refactoring because of `document.createTextNode(txt);`. Too much work if you don't fix your layout above.

Comment: I just recopied and repasted it directly from the JS file.

Comment: Sure, and I'm saying that if you want help, you should spend a couple of seconds cleaning up the formatting so we make sense of it.

Comment: And you rolled back someone else's edit? They were trying to help.

Comment: @ZachNicodemous - why did you take out all the indentation that I carefully edited in.  Your code is completely unreadable as it is now.  I carefully put indentation into it to make it readable to the other StackOverflow readers and then you took it all out again.  Makes not sense to me.  Do you like unreadable code?

Comment: jfriend00 - im sorry but I didnt realize you had edited it.  when I clicked to edit my question, it didnt show me the edit you'd made.  I apologize.

Comment: @ZachNicodemous - when posting code in a question or answer, you need to learn how to show proper indentation to make the code readable.  It makes your question a lot more likely to get answers and makes the site more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is way over complex.  I'd suggest replacing the `myTime()` function with this that just builds HTML rather than create all the various text nodes.  This also puts the AM or PM designation in a `<span class="ampm">` so it can be styled appropriately:

```
function myTime() {
    var dst = 0; // set to 1 for daylight savings time
    // update this as you go on and off daylight saving time
    var loc = ''; // set to your location
    var mtz = -5; // set to your local timezone (hours ahead of UTC, negative if behind)
    var stdz = ''; // standard time indicator
    var dayz = ''; // daylight saving time indicator (blank if you dont have daylight saving)
    var showDate = 0; // 0 = don't show, 1 = international format, 2 = US format

    var timeStr = setDsp(mtz, dst, stdz, dayz, showDate);
    timeStr = timeStr.replace(/AM|PM/i, '<span class="ampm">$&</span>');
    var d = document.getElementById('datetime');
    d.innerHTML = '<div id="time">' + loc + " " + timeStr + '</div>';
    setTimeout(myTime, 500);
}
```

And here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jTbf2/